# Static page with custom content depending on url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I used to use parts of the url address to add words to a page template when I worked with PHP.

I've started looking at static pages using https://gohugo.io and trying to get this function in JavaScript in order not to need to generate multiple pages (Although this is the point of static pages) since all url will use the same page template but with difrent text from the url.

Example (from my PHP site)

```
url = www.domain.tld/city/washington/
Where i get the word after /city/ and put the word "washington" in my page content.
```

```
url = www.domain.tld/city/somecityname/
Where i get the word after /somecityname/ and put the word "washington" in my page content.
```

I looked at https://gohugo.io/extras/datafiles/ and https://gohugo.io/extras/datadrivencontent/ but this wont fix it the way i want it to be. (although I have a csv file with the city names)

Page will be hosted on GitHub Pages so i can only use Javascript / jQuery for this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code for get city name

```
var qrStr1 = window.location.href;
var new1 = qrStr1.replace(':',''); 
var data1 = new1.split("/");
alert(data1[4]);// try with different index so you can find your value
```

Comment: This is the way in PHP, I forgot to add that I do not have the ability to run PHP on the server side, the page will be on GitHub Pages so i need to do this function in Javascript / jQuery.

Comment: Great code, this is as far as i gone for now to, problem is that if i enter "cityname" after "city" browser try to find a page named that.

But if i enter the url like www.domain.tld/city/?washington/ it will stay one the city page and i can get the "?washington" part of the url.

Is there a more SEO friendly way of doing this?

Comment: send me your full url so i can understand what you want

Comment: try this one   var qrStr1 = window.location.href;
var data1 = qrStr1.split("?");
  console.log(data1[1]);